# How to display MKCompassButton with swiftui

Tags: mapkit, swiftui

I'm using swiftui and I would like to display the compass button.
The map portion of my code is derived from this tutorial:
https://www.morningswiftui.com/blog/build-mapview-app-with-swiftui

I've looked at sample code to display the compass on the map but I have not been able to find an example that I can get working with my swiftui code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually compass is showing, but only when you try to turn your map. If you want to see compass button for all the time, you can add your own button in `makeUIView` func:

```swift
struct RootMapView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let map = MKMapView()
        map.showsCompass = false // hides current compass, which shows only on map turning

        let compassBtn = MKCompassButton(mapView: map)
        compassBtn.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20) // you may use GeometryReader to replace it's position
        compassBtn.compassVisibility = .visible // compass will always be on map
        map.addSubview(compassBtn)

        return map
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was looking for!